# How do I get bootstrap modal to display above each image?

Tags: css, meteor, bootstrap-modal

I have a meteor query that returns a cursor with images data. I use bootstrap to arrange the images to display responsively. When each image is clicked I'd like a bootstrap modal to display/appear right above the clicked image. Is this possible? Any one care to demonstrate how to archive this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible. Easiest way is to [use this package](https://atmospherejs.com/peppelg/bootstrap-3-modal) You can then proceed to create a modal, just like any other template and call `Modal.show("myAwesomeModal");` from the click event of the image.

I could explain with some code, if you think you're stuck. But for the most part, the documentaion of the package will help.